# List of products - align some elements on the bottom of the col

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to align some elements on the bottom of the div, while keeping other elements on top.
While I was able to do partial job, I am unable to make it 'pretty' - my elements are not aligned properly and there is no good space between elements. 
What am I doing wrong, any suggestions?

I added my CSS:

```
.bottom_align {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

I am new to bootstrap and CSS is not my strongest suite, any advise?

I created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p382qby6/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use position : relative to manage gap between elements.

```
.bottom_align {
    position: relative;
   /* margin-top: some px; */
/* margin-bottom: some px; */
}
```